# How to conditionally pass data into a function using currying

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I'm somewhat new to functional programming.  Here is my current paradigm from my React app.  I have a generic component into which I'm passing a function which can optionally take a `placeholder` argument.

```
<TableColumn field="effectiveDate" format={dateFormatter} sortable>Start Date</TableColumn>
<TableColumn field="endDate" format={dateFormatter("No End Date")} sortable>End Date</TableColumn>
```

I believe I need to use currying to acheive my goal (which I'll speak to shortly).  That being the case, I've defined `dateFormatter` like this:

```
export function dateFormatter(placeholder?: string) {
  return function (date: string) {
    const attributes: any = { value: date };
    if (placeholder) {
      attributes.placeholder = placeholder;
    }
    return <ShortDate {...attributes} />;
  };
}
```

Then, when I actually render my table, I loop through each record and get the value like this:

```
getRecordValue(record: any, column: React.ReactElement<TableColumnProps>) {
    const { format, field } = column.props;
    const cell = field ? record[field] : "";
    if (format) {
      return format()(cell, record);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I want to have a single `dateFormatter` function, but be able to optionally pass a `placeholder` and defer execution.  How can I do this?

Comment: Why use currying and not just ES6 default values?

Comment: @GerardvanHelden I only want to use placeholder if it's specified.

Comment: `<TableColumn ... format={dateFormatter()} />` and inside `getRecordValue` `... if (format) { return format(cell); } ...` Currying is taking place when the `<TableColumn />` is rendered. Then `getRecordValue` will have access to the optionally captured `placeholder`.

Comment: which is your *current paradigm*?

Comment: @naomik I better asked my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909062/optionally-pass-parameter-to-function-being-passed-around/47909105#47909105

Answer (score 0):

just use props. Check if the parrent has passed certain props, in your case is `format`.

```
class App extends React.component{
  render(){
     <CustomComponent  format={dateFormatter("No End Date")}/>
  }
}

class CustomComponent extends React.component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
     <div>
       Your content maybe
       { this.props.format && this.props.format }
     </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: I've either poorly explained my problem or you've misunderstood it.

Comment: I guess it's the first.

Comment: @CatalinBesleaga he's looking for a functional-style solution.  `class`/`extends` is oo-style and is only used for stateful components. stateless (props-only) components can be *composed* (using functions) rather than *extended* (using classes)