# Optionally pass parameter to function being passed around

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, functional-programming

I have the following function:

```
export function dateFormatter(date: string) {
  return moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
}
```

I have a React component where I'm able to pass the function like this:

```
<TableColumn field="endDate" format={dateFormatter}>End Date</TableColumn>
```

That component calls the function like this:

```
const { format, field } = column.props;
if (format) {
  return format(cell);
}
return cell;
```

All of this works fine.  I would now like to alter my `dateFormatter` function so that I can optionally pass a parameter into it.  I'm unclear on how to do this because if I change the reference to:

```
<TableColumn field="endDate" format={dateFormatter("MM/YY")}>End Date</TableColumn>
```

It will pass that format as the date into my function.

How can I optionally pass a parameter into a function that I will then pass around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting a function that does the formatting, export a function that *makes* a function:

```
export function makeFormatter(format: string) {
  return function(date: string) {
    return moment(date).format(format || "MM/DD/YYYY");
  };
}
```

When you use the function, you'll insert a *call* to `makeFormatter()` with the desired format (or nothing to get the default). You could of course pre-make several different formatting functions for convenience:

```
var formatters = {
  mmddyyyy: makeFormatter("MM/DD/YYYY"),
  euro: makeFormatter("DD/MM/YYYY"),
  datetime: makeFormatter("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm"),
  // etc
};
```

Then you can use `formatters.mmddyyyy` in the code to get that formatter.

Comment: Brutal.  I had actually implemented the (I believe it's called "currying") solution you just suggested, but couldn't get it to work for the default instance.  For the default case, I was calling it like `format={dateFormatter}` instead of `format={dateFormatter()}`.  After adding the `()`, it now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your function as follows:

```
export function dateFormatter(format: string) {
  return (date: string = "MM/DD/YYYY") => moment(date).format(format);
}
```

It will return a function that returns a date, with a default value of "MM/DD/YYYY".

So your component will be using this like

```
<TableColumn fromat={dateFormatter()}/>
```

or

```
<TableColumn fromat={dateFormatter("MM/DD")}/>
```